# What does it mean when Repair Disk takes just a few seconds to complete?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, leopard, startup, repair

I have the flashing finder icon problem. When I boot from DVD, I cannot choose the disk as Startup Disk. However, it appears in Disk Utility. When I run Repair Disk I can see the disk, and that it has about 130GB used, but Repair Disk takes literally about four seconds -- a suspiciously short amount of time. By contrast, Repair Disk on the external takes about three minutes.

What is the best explanation for this?

Comment: Disk Utility has a log that lists the checks as you perform them. You probable are doing different checks but without comparing the two runs, it could be a wrapper vs a volume check but hard to know without more detail

Answer (score 1):

Checking a disk checks the partition map but not the volume data structures.

Checking a volume checks the partition itself, which can take much longer.